# pandas to_numeric not casting empty dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need a dataframe with all dtypes which are subsets of `np.number`. The to_numeric function allows me to do this for dataframes which have some data. As a corner case, I was testing it with an empty dataframe, where it does not seem to work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print(df.dtypes)
```

gives me the output

```
col1   object
col2   object
col3   object
dtype: object
```

where I expect

```
col1   int64
col2   int64
col3   int64
dtype: object
```

If I fill the dataframe, then the problem disappears:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [1, 2], 'col3': [1, 2]})
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print(df.dtypes)
```

gives me the expected output.

Can someone explain this different behaviour, and suggest a workaround. I do not want to explicitly check if the dataframe has data or not unless required.

I am working with **python 3.6.1**

Comment: Since there are no elements, your `apply` does nothing

Comment: If you want numeric dtypes on empty `df` use `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], dtype=int)`

Comment: because if your result is empty, `.apply` simply returns a copy of your data-frame.

Comment: So you are saying that apply is the problem here, because it looks for elements to work upon. @SaiKumar, I can do that, but I do want to use the 'coerce' argument that to_numeric offers, and I was wondering if there is a way to not explicitly distinguish dataframes which do and do not have data.

Answer (score 1):

Using [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) seems to achieve it

```
df=df.astype("int64")
```

You can also explicitly assign types to each column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':pd.Series([], dtype='int'),
               'col2':pd.Series([], dtype='int'),
               'col3':pd.Series([], dtype='int')})

print(df.dtypes)

col1    int64
col2    int64
col3    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: kind of, but only if you make an inplace copy.

Comment: @d_kennetz how is that an issue

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I can use astype, yes, but I will still need to distinguish explicitly between cases with and without data. I do not want to lose the coerced casting ability of pandas.to_numeric when I do have non-numeric data.

Is there a way I can have a single statement fit all cases?